# Sentence meaning in context

Tags: understanding

> The reasoning in the argument is **most** vulnerable to criticism on the
>   grounds that the argument
>
> A)_____ B)_____ C)_____

For me, it sounds like **most** should be eliminated in order for the sentence to be correct, since "criticism" is a singular in this sentence. If the sentence is "The reasoning in the argument is most vulnerable to which one of the criticisms?" then it would sound ok with the word **most**. Am I thinking incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**the reasoning** is most vulnerable （which is among other hidden factors, like judging, concluding, etc）. It's not the point whether "criticism" is singular or not.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, criticism is an uncounted noun; it refers to the act or process of criticism, rather than to a specific objection to the argument. It could also be phrased "Most vulnerable to **attack**" in the same way.

**Most vulnerable** in this context implies that the argument may be vulnerable to criticism in other ways, but this particular objection to it is the most obvious or the strongest.

Comment: Is it ok to use the word "most" even if there are no other things to compare?

Comment: Yes. Using **most** implies that other things are possible, but they do not have to be explicitly listed. I might say that a fire is **most likely** to start in the kitchen, without having to list other places it might start as well.